# Extracting a cytochrome B sequence from NCBI's nucleotide database

Tags: database, nucleotide-models, efetch

Can someone tell the way to extract the fasta sequences for the gene cytb of *Acetes japonicus* (shrimp important to China and South Korea)?

Can I extract them directly from NCBI nucleotide database (i.e. nuccore)?

For instance, I'm trying to fetch the fasta data of *Acetes japonicus* of cytb gene. So I'm using biopython, like this:

```
 handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide", term="Acetes japonicus[Orgn] AND cytb[Gene]")
record=Entrez.read(handle)
```

And the output doesn't give the an ID, however when I search manually I get the result.

Comment: What sequences? The gene? The CDS? The various spliced transcripts? Protein? In what species? Please [edit] and make your question more specific and we can give you specific answers.

Comment: Weird, when I search the nucleotide database, I see only COI gene. You can try handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide", term="Acetes japonicus[Orgn] AND COI[Gene]",idtype="acc") and you will see that it works. Substitute COI for cytb and it's empty. Exactly what I saw in entrez nucleotide database

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is it normal for the results to appear in the form o html?

Comment: You are referring to results of Entrez.read(handle) ? It's a something like a dictionary. You can check with type(record)

Comment: @StupidWolf I concur: I also only see COI.  There are no 'cytb' sequences for this species, and that is why you get 0 hits.

Answer (score 0):

I should have answered correctly ages back, because I do know it.

Cytochrome b is a massively used target for arthropods - these are shrimps. However, the nomenclature changed:

- Traditionally nomenclature `cytb`
- 'New' nomenclature `COB`

Wait you might ask, arn't you confusing that with COI, II, III?  No because that nomenclature changed too:

- Traditional nomenclature `COI`
- 'New' nomenclature `COX1`

'New' was a long time ago though.

Thus the gene you are looking for is MZ571562, [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/MZ571562.1)

```
 ... AND COB [gene]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it from command line version:

```
esearch -db nuccore -query "COB [GENE] AND "Acetes japonicus" [ORGN]"|efetch -format gb
```

OR

```
esearch -db nuccore -query "COB [GENE] AND "Acetes japonicus" [ORGN]"|efetch -format fasta
```

Note that gene name is actually COB.